# suitable ruby on rails cms with excellent documentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system

working with a small database,users and a minimal design are the most important needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only want to do basic CRUD operations, and given the powerful scaffolding Rails has, I'd just take a few hours to build your own. If you need user authentication, simply use Devise and you should be all set.